# ЧПУ и .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Есть вот такой код

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/? index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Когда входишь на 
http://localhost/document/1/ - всё работает норм

а если

http://localhost/document/ - ошибка

Как сделать что бы вторая переменная была не обязательной?

Comment: Дмитрий, подскажите мануалы на тему вашего примера! Где вы такое нашли?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?([0-9]+)?/? index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Сейчас если ссылка
http://localhost/document/1 (без слеша в конце) то id вообще не передается

и пропали все картинки на странице

Comment: Вы уверены что все скопировали? Вот что у меня выдает var_dump($_GET); размещенный в самом начале index.php, если я обращаюсь по адресу "http://localhost/document/1" - `array(2) { ["page"]=> string(8) "document" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" }`. P.S. и тоже самое если я обращаюсь по томуже адресу, но со слешем в конце.